# Firebase database fetching a number of nodes at a time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that pagination is a well discussed topic here but... Is there a way to fetch some amount of nodes(something like 5 at a time) and know when the end has been reached? Firebase Database does not have a way of knowing the total number of nodes. So how will I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know if you have *all* the data at a location is to perform a single 'value' type query on it.  Even then, the data may change after that listener is invoked, so all you really have is a snapshot at a particular moment in tim.

For child events, there is no way to know there is no more data after the current event.  In fact, child events may keep firing as more data is added, as long as the listener is still added at that location.

This is why pagination is so hard.  There is no generalized way to know if you have a full page of data at any given point, or if there's another page.

Comment: So, @Doug can you please show me how I can like fetch 10 nodes at a time and feed it to a viewpager that triggers retrieval of more data when its on like the last 2 nodes from the 10 nodes that are fetched? The viewpager shows posts that users have posted and is navigated by swiping, If this is not a good practice can you tell me how else i can implement this? Oh and its compulsory that i have the swiping feature. Forgive my illiteracy I'm a beginner. :)